# Прогресс-бар картинкой

Tags: javascript, php, css

Опыта в php и css у меня всего пара месяцев. Возникла необходимость сделать красивый прогресс-бар для браузерной онлайн-игры в виде картинкок(одна из них задняя, а вторая накладывается на другую), их ширина зависит  от формулы, из которой выводится показатели пользователя. Всё вышло, но картинка сжимается если она занимает меньше 100% области, дабы полностью поместиться в неё. Суть моего вопроса заключается в следующем: как сделать прогресс-бар в виде фоновой картинки, ширина которой будет задаваться в % в зависимости от показателя из формулы. Т.е, допустим, в формуле получилось 70, нужно чтобы отобразилось 70% картинки без сжатия. Возможно, мой способ вообще не правильный.

Это стили

```
#download_1{
background: 
url(/style/download_user_1.jpg);
background-size: cover; 
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
#download_2{
background: 
url(/style/download_user_2.jpg);
background-size: cover; 
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Одна из формул

```
$life_hp=($datas['hp'])/($datas['hp_max'])*100;
```

Код с самим прогресс-баром

```
<div id="download_1" style="width:200px; height: 10px">
<div id="download_2" style="height: 10px; width: '.$life_hp.'%;">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну чтобы не деформировать картинку кроме width можно еще менять background-size по x в обратной пропорции. Вот пример на js https://codepen.io/Manfrid/pen/qBNQjaJ

Comment: К сожалению, вообще не получается. Пробывал в блоках вместо свойства width указать background-size, но картинка просто растягивается на всю область. Мне нужно чтобы именно часть картинки отображалась, в зависимости от показателя пользователя если формулы, что в выше. Если это 100% то 100% картинки, если 30% то 30% процентов картинки, и чтобы это не сжималось

Comment: вам надо менять width и background-size(только в обратной пропорции)

Comment: Спасибо большое